# Finding data from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

**I am trying to find the jobs location in Dayton that require either database or analysis skills, then ordered by company and job id.**

It should be the following:

Database ('s1'): j06, j07, j08, and j10

Analysis ('s7'): j07 and j14

This is the script used for this!!

```
drop table Jobskills;
drop table Appskills;
drop table Applies;
drop table Applicant;
drop table Skills;
drop table Job;
drop table Company;

create table Company(compid char(5) primary key, compname varchar(20), 
                     comptype varchar(15));
create table Job(jobid char(5) primary key, jobtitle varchar(20),
                 salarylow int, salaryhigh int, location char(10), 
                 compid references Company(compid) on delete cascade);
create table Skills(skillid char(5) primary key, skillname varchar(15));
create table Jobskills(jobid references Job(jobid) on delete cascade, 
                       skillid references Skills(skillid), 
               expertiseneeded int, primary key(jobid,skillid));
create table Applicant(appid char(5) primary key, name varchar(15), 
                       age int, highdegree char(5), expected_salary int) ;
create table AppSkills(appid references Applicant(appid) on delete cascade, 
                       skillid references Skills(skillid), expertise int,
                       primary key(appid, skillid));
create table Applies(jobid references Job(jobid), 
                     appid references Applicant(appid) on delete cascade, 
                     appdate date, decisiondate date, outcome char(10),  
                     primary key(jobid, appid));

rem Initial Company data
insert into Company values('PWC', 'Price Waterhouse', 'consulting');
insert into Company values('MSFT', 'Microsoft', 'software');
insert into Company values('INTL', 'Intel', 'electronics');
insert into Company values('NCR', 'NCR Corp', 'server');
insert into Company values('WPAF', 'WP Air Force', 'defense');
insert into Company values('DLT', 'Deloitte', 'consulting');

rem Initial Job data
insert into Job values('101', 'Programmer', 55000, 60000, 'Redmond', 'MSFT');
insert into Job values('j02', 'Designer', 42000, 45000, 'Redmond', 'MSFT');
insert into Job values('j03', 'SAP impl', 30000, 40000, 'Chicago', 'PWC');
insert into Job values('j04', 'Proj mgmt', 35000, 55000, 'Chicago', 'PWC');
insert into Job values('j05', 'SOX', 60000, 65000, 'Detroit', 'PWC');
insert into Job values('j06', 'db admin', 45000, 50000, 'Dayton', 'NCR');
insert into Job values('j07', 'db designer', 35000, 40000, 'Dayton', 'NCR');
insert into Job values('j08', 'intern', 25000, 28000, 'Dayton', 'NCR');
insert into Job values('j09', 'engineer', 52000, 55000, 'Dayton','WPAF');
insert into Job values('j10', 'dba', 62000, 65000, 'Dayton','WPAF');
insert into Job values('j11', 'hardware dev', 50000, 65000, 'NYC','INTL');
insert into Job values('j12', 'pcb designer', 55000, 68000,'NYC','INTL');
insert into Job values('j13', 'chip designer', 40000, 55000,'Chicago','INTL');
insert into Job values('j14', 'IT', 40000, 60000, 'Dayton', 'DLT');
insert into Job values('j15', 'IT', 50000, 70000, 'Chicago', 'DLT');

rem initial Skills data
insert into Skills values('s1', 'database');
insert into Skills values('s2', 'programming');
insert into Skills values('s3', 'sox');
insert into Skills values('s4', 'project');
insert into Skills values('s5', 'hardware');
insert into Skills values('s6', 'sap');
insert into Skills values('s7', 'analysis');

rem Initial Jobskills data
insert into Jobskills values('101', 's2', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('101', 's7', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j02', 's2', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j02', 's7', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j03', 's6', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j04', 's7', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j04', 's4', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j04', 's2', 2);
insert into Jobskills values('j05', 's3', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j06', 's1', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j06', 's2', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j07', 's1', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j07', 's7', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j08', 's1', 2);
insert into Jobskills values('j09', 's2', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j09', 's4', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j10', 's4', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j10', 's1', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j11', 's5', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j11', 's4', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j12', 's5', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j13', 's1', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j13', 's2', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j14', 's7', 4);

rem initial Applicants data
insert into Applicant values('a1', 'Joe', 30, 'MS', 55000);
insert into Applicant values('a2', 'Monica', 25, 'BS', 62000);
insert into Applicant values('a3', 'Jim', 22, 'BS', 45000);
insert into Applicant values('a4', 'Monica', 25, 'BS', 34000);

rem initial Appskills data
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's1', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's2', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's4', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's6', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's7', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a2', 's2', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a2', 's3', 5);
insert into Appskills values('a2', 's6', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a3', 's4', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a3', 's1', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a3', 's2', 5);

rem Applies
insert into Applies values ('101', 'a1', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('101', 'a2', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('j02', 'a2', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('j04', 'a2', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('j02', 'a3', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'nohire');
insert into Applies values ('j04', 'a3', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'nohire');
insert into Applies values ('j06', 'a3', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'nohire');
```

This is my code so far...

```
SELECT j.location, j.jobid, js.skillid
FROM jobskills js INNER JOIN job j ON js.jobid = j.jobid
WHERE j.location = 'Dayton'
    AND (js.skillid = 's1' OR js.skillid = 's7')
ORDER BY j.jobid
```

I just need to add the company name, but every time I add that it messes up my whole code.

Comment: Why do you think you'd join on `compID`? Don't you think joining from `jobid` to `skillid` would be better to *"figure out how to add the skill ID in here"*? --- Let's see, ..., maybe the **`Jobskills`** table might help with that. Have a look at that and try again. --- That one seems so self-evident to me, that I'm wondering if you really tried to do this yourself, or if you're just here hoping we'd write your code for you. That is not what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: @Andreas this is my first time taking an SQL class and I have been trying to solve this problem for awhile now that I decided to seek some help. How would I benefit by just asking for the code? I'm genuinely trying to figure this out, but I am NOT expecting anyone to write this for me.

Comment: _"How would I benefit by just asking for the code? I'm genuinely trying to figure this out, but I am NOT expecting anyone to write this for me"_   Kudos for your attitude.  But you'd be surprised how many people who post here _are_ just expecting someone to just do their homework for them.  Hence the early responses.  Now, just expect that people will tend to ask you leading questions designed to help lead you to self-discovery (and better understanding) of the solution.

Comment: @EdStevens thank you, I understand that and I was not looking for someone to do it for me. His suggestion was enough to help me think differently on how to work on this, but the rest of his comment was unnecessary. Can you help me? I think I figured out more of this but I just need one thing. I'm going to update my original post.

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? Please tag only the DBMS you are really using. (Btw: in MySQL all of your "inline" foreign keys are ignored)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to inner join company with job on compid.

```
SELECT c.compname,j.location, j.jobid, js.skillid
FROM jobskills js INNER JOIN job j ON js.jobid = j.jobid
inner join company c on c.compid=j.compid
WHERE j.location = 'Dayton'
    AND (js.skillid = 's1' OR js.skillid = 's7')
ORDER BY j.jobid
```

**Ourput:**

```
|COMPNAME    |LOCATION  |JOBID |SKILLID|
|------------|----------|------|-------|
|NCR Corp    |Dayton    |j06   |s1     |
|NCR Corp    |Dayton    |j07   |s1     |
|NCR Corp    |Dayton    |j07   |s7     |
|NCR Corp    |Dayton    |j08   |s1     |
|WP Air Force|Dayton    |j10   |s1     |
|Deloitte    |Dayton    |j14   |s7     |
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I could do 2 `INNER JOIN` like that. That was what kept messing up my code.